# Adjust String timestamp to GMT

Tags: java

I have a `String` with local time:

```
"2012-12-12T08:26:51+000"
```

I now need to create a `String` with GMT time based on the old `String`. For example, assuming 2 hours difference between local and GTM:

```
"2012-12-12T10:26:51+000"
```

I have created a `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSS"); 
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String time = dateFormat.parse(mCreatedTime).toString();
```

But the `time` String is now in different format:

```
Wed Dec 12 etc
```

How do I get the output to be in format `yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSS` but GMT time?

Comment: Have you tried `Z` for time zone? I don't think `+SSSS` will do what you think.

Comment: You say that 2012-12-12T08:26:51+000 is your local time, but offset with GMT is +000. Maybe you mean +0200?

Comment: The format of your string seems messed up. You apparently meant for "+000" to represent milliseconds (given your use of SSSS in the format string). But the "+" PLUS SIGN usually means offset from UTC/GMT.

Comment: Another bug in the question: Show 3 digits of zeros in milliseconds, but 4 characters of "SSSS" in format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dateFormat.parse()` method returns an instance of Date, and when you call `toString()` on it the date will be printed in the default locale.

Use `dateFormat.format()` to get your Date value back to your required format.

Answer (score 0):

As my comments on this question suggest, I believe the original poster of this question is confused and miseducated about date-time work. Nevertheless, I wrote some example code delivering exactly what Pierre asked for, along with my caveat that he is following some very bad practices.

Using Joda-Time 2.3 library and Java 7.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

// CAUTION: The question asked specifically for the format used here.
// But this format incorrectly uses the PLUS SIGN to mean milliseconds rather than offset from UTC/GMT.
// Very bad thing to do. Will create no end of confusion.
// Another bad thing: This code creates strings representing date-times in different time zones without indicating they are in different time zones.

// Time Zone list: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
// "Atlantic/South_Georgia" is a time zone two hours behind UTC.
DateTimeZone southGeorgiaZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Atlantic/South_Georgia" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSS" );
DateTime dateTimeInSouthGeorgia = formatter.withZone( southGeorgiaZone ).parseDateTime( "2012-12-12T08:26:51+000" );
DateTime dateTimeInUtc = dateTimeInSouthGeorgia.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
String screwyBadPracticeDateTimeString = formatter.print( dateTimeInUtc );

System.out.println( "2012-12-12T08:26:51+000 in southGeorgiaDateTime: " + dateTimeInSouthGeorgia );
System.out.println( "same, in UTC: " + dateTimeInUtc );
System.out.println( "screwyBadPracticeDateTimeString: " + screwyBadPracticeDateTimeString );
```

When run…

```
2012-12-12T08:26:51+000 in southGeorgiaDateTime: 2012-12-12T08:26:51.000-02:00
same, in UTC: 2012-12-12T10:26:51.000Z
screwyBadPracticeDateTimeString: 2012-12-12T10:26:51+000
```